# Ambiguous table Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the error message "table is ambiguous.  I am using aliases so unsure why the table is ambiguous.  Here is my code:

```
UPDATE Field_Translations
    SET SourceColumn1='EnteredProduct'
        ,SourceValue1=I.Product
        ,TargetColumn1='NewProduct'
        ,TargetValue1='Not Reported'
        ,TargetColumn2='NewProductId'
        ,TargetValue2=-1
    FROM Org8_28_17 I
        LEFT JOIN Field_Translations FT ON I.Vendor=FT.SourceValue1 AND FT.SourceColumn1='HGVendor'
        LEFT JOIN Field_Translations FT2 ON I.Product=FT2.SourceValue1 AND FT2.SourceColumn1='HGProduct' 
    WHERE FT.TargetValue1 IS NOT NULL AND FT2.TargetValue1 IS NULL --AND I.Product like '%(%'
        AND I.Vendor=I.Product AND I.Vendor=FT.TargetValue1
```

Comment: One of your column names is the same across multiple tables.  You aliased the FROM so why dont you use it in the columns you've listed?  In addition, UPDATE ft SET i.SC=...FROM MyTable ft

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you alias the table name in the FROM clause, you must use the alias in the UPDATE clause:

`UPDATE FT`

Not

`UPDATE Field_Translations`

Your use of `Field_Translations` is ambiguous because you have joined to it twice.